# UseState() never updating even after component re-render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a function to add devices to a room. I have succeed to create a `const newDevice` using the `Class Device`receiving 2 parameters: `(deviceName, deviceStatus)`.
My problem is that for some reason when I try to add the created new device to the array `devices` using the useState hook
`const [devices,setDevices]=useState([])`, the array remains empty even after re-rendering several times the component.
How can I push the data from `newDevice`to the array `devices`?

Here is the entire code:

```
  
  const [devices,setDevices]=useState([])
  
  const [deviceName,setDeviceName]=useState('')
  const [deviceStatus,setDeviceStatus]=useState('off')

  
  
  
  const AddDevice=(deviceName,deviceStatus)=>{
    
    const newDevice = new Device(deviceName, deviceStatus);
    console.log(newDevice); //Device {deviceName: 'AC', deviceStatus: 'off'} OK

    setDevices([...devices,newDevice]); //never add newDevice to the array ever after re-render
    console.log(devices); //returns []
      
      
      
      let devicesList=currentRoom.devicesList

      devicesList.push(devices)
      console.log(devicesList);
      console.log(currentRoom);

      show(false)

      showAddDevice()

      return newDevice
    
    
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
  
      <select  value={deviceName} onChange={(e)=>setDeviceName(e.target.value)}>
        <option value="" disabled selected >Choose device...</option>

          <option>Light</option>  
          <option>AC</option>  
          <option>Boiler</option>  
          <option>TV</option>  
          <option>Stereo</option>  
        </select>
      
      <button onClick={()=>AddDevice(deviceName,deviceStatus)}>Add device</button>
    </div>
  )
}

class Device {
  constructor(deviceName, deviceStatus) {
    this.deviceName = deviceName;
    this.deviceStatus = deviceStatus;
  }
}
```

Comment: it's working . just move the console.log outside the  `AddDevice` function so it get the value whenever the state changes

Comment: ok I just did that but still ```devices``` remains empty. I really cant get why

Answer (score 0):

It's likely an issue with your parent component (or even `devicesList`, `show()`, or `showAddDevice()`). The relevant code runs as expected in sandbox.

https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-shadow-z1ivnm?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Exactly it appears that```showAddDevice()```caused this issue. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yep, not a problem!